# Selection Sort on x86 Assembly

Tags: c, sorting, assembly, x86, selection

This is a homework if anyone's curious.

The task is to have a C program create a 2D array and pass that array into assembly which it should be sorted using selection sort.

The error I'm having when trying to run it is segmentation fault. I've tried putting

```
push tesst
push sout
call printf
```

to print out "test" on the terminal window but I couldn't figure out where it's coming from. I also tried putting it right after "enter 0,0" and I still havent gotten a print out of test. So i'm completely out of ideas as to where i'm getting the segmentation fault.

Any assistance would be very much appreciated. :( Due tomorrow night and i've been stuck at this for a couple of days. Someone shed some light please

-Chris

The codes will be below

my c program

> ```
> #include <stdio.h>
>
> int ssort(char * hi[], int x, int y);
>
> int main(){
>
>   int i, j;
>
>
>   char hi[3][5] = {"Yoshi", "Annie", "Chris"};
>
>   printf("Display Unsorted Strings\n");
>   for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
>     for(j = 0; j < 5; j++){
>       printf("%c", hi[i][j]);
>     }
>     printf("\n");
>   }
>   printf("It Got Here\n");
>   ssort((char*)hi, 5, 3);
>   printf("Sorted\n");
>   for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
>     for(j = 0; j < 5; j++){
>       printf("%c", hi[i][j]);
>     }
>     printf("\n");
>   }
> }
> ```

And my Assembly Code

> ```
> extern    printf
>
> segment   .data
>
> tesst db  't','e','s','t',0
> sout  db  "%s", 10, 0
>
> segment   .text
>
>   global  ssort
>
> ssort:    
>   enter   0,0
>
> ;;; for(i = 0; i < namecount; i++){
> ;;;   for(j = 1; j < namecount; j++){
> ;;;       if(array[i] < array[j])
> ;;;           do nothing
> ;;;       else
> ;;;           swap
> ;;;   }
> ;;; }
>
>
>   mov esi,    [ebp+8] 
>   mov edi,    esi
>   add edi,    [ebp+8]
>   mov ecx,    0   ;i
>   mov edx,    0
>   add edx,    1   ;j
>   ;; [ebp+16] = namecount
>
> iloop:
>   push    esi
>   cmp ecx,    [ebp+16]
>   je  done_sorting
> jloop:
>   cmp edx,    [ebp+16]
>   je  j_done
>
> ;;; compare here now
> compare:
>   mov al, [esi]
>   mov bl, [edi]
>   cmp al, bl
>   jg  alisbigger
>   jl  blisbigger
>   inc esi
>   inc edi
>   jmp compare
> alisbigger:   
>   jmp swap
> blisbigger:   
>   jmp done
>
> swap:
>   mov ebx,    0
>   mov ebx,    [ebp+12]
> swap_loop:
>   dec ebx
>
>   mov al, [esi]
>   mov bl, [edi]
>   mov [esi],  bl
>   mov [edi],  al
>
>   inc esi
>   inc edi
>
>   cmp ebx,    0
>   je  done
>   jmp swap_loop
>
> done:
>   inc edx
>   jmp jloop
>
> j_done:
>   add ecx, 1
>   add esi, [ebp+12]
>   mov edx, 1
>   jmp iloop   
>
>
> done_sorting:
>   leave
>   ret
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Print-style debugging is okay in situations where there's nothing else available but *nothing* beats getting down and dirty inside a source level debugger.

*Step 1:* Probably the easiest way is to first take out the call into assembly and run it, to ensure it's not your C code causing the problem.

*Step 2:* Then, put the call back in and load it into `gdb` or your favorite source level debugger. Set a breakpoint on the first assembler instruction. When it breaks, examine the stack to ensure it's what you expect.

*Step 3:* Then single step through the assembly until you find your problem.

That will be the best way for you to learn, and to quickly find and fix your problem.

---

I will tell you *one* thing I see as a potential problem. Just after the `iloop` label, you have `push esi`. I can't see a `pop` (or other `esp`-modifying statement) *anywhere* in your code and, worse yet, that `push` is happening in a loop.

If you try to return from a function with the stack pointer different to what it was when you entered, you're in for a *world* of pain. I may just have missed something but I'd start by looking there.

Comment: Thanks Problem in the compare() I didn't even know bout gdb til now. I say witch craft! :P thanks a lot

Comment: Noted and fixed. Thanks again